# How to prove triangle inequality for given formula?

Tags: inequality, triangles

How to prove that given formula $\frac{(P-Q)^2}{P}+\frac{(P-Q)^2}{Q}$ satisfies triangle inequality ?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality. If $d(P,Q)$ is given by your formula, then
$$d(1,2)=3/2,\ d(2,3)=5/6,\ d(1,3)=16/3.$$ But $3/2+5/6=7/3<16/3.$